# Run shiny modules with promises

Tags: r, shiny, promise, parallel-processing

I want to run several shiny modules in parallel. I know there is promises that I can use but I need some guides or explanation of how to run the modules in parallel.

Here is my main ui and server code with the different modules call. Note that all the modules scripts are too big I can't share them here.

```
#Libraries
source("global/libraries.R")

#### call modules #####
list.files("modules") %>% purrr::map(~ source(paste0("modules/", .)))
#### call modules #####


#### Connect to Production database #####
source("global/DBconnect.R")
#### End Connect to database #####


#### Initialize global dataframe ####
source("global/dataframe.R")
#### End Initialize global dataframe ####

#### Initialize global functions#### 
source("functions/functions.R")
#### End Initialize global functions ####



#### Create User Interface #####
ui <-
  tagList(  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(# the javascript is checking the screen resolution to adapt the display
      tags$script(src = "javascripts.js")),
    tags$style(HTML(
      paste(
        "html,",
        ".container{
                    width: 100%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    padding: 0;
                }
               @media screen and (min-width: 700px){
                .container{
                    min-width: 1850px;
                    max-width: 1920px;
                }
               }
                          ",
        sep = " "
      )
    )),
    tags$div(
      class = "container",
      dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
        dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
        dashboardBody(
          
          tags$head(
            tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")
          ),
          #UI for Country
          reporter_download_ui(id = "reporterdownload"),
          #End of UI for Country
          
          #UI for Demographics
           demographics_ui(id = "demographics"),
          #End of UI for Demographics

          #UI for Trade in goods
          tradeingoods_1_ui(id = "tradeingoods"),
          #End of UI for Trade in goods

          #UI for Trade Performance
          trade_performance_ui(id = "tradeperformance"),
          # #End of UI Trade Performance
          #
          # #UI for Logistic Performance
           LPI_ui(id = "LPI"),
          # #End of UI Logistic Performance

          # #UI for Bilateral Trade
          bilateral_ui(id = "bilateral"),
          #End of UI Bilateral Trade

          #UI for Trade Agreements
          trade_agreement_ui(id = "agreement"),
          #End of UI Trade Agreements

          #UI for Trade in services
          # tradeinservices_ui(id = "tradeinservices"),
          #End of UI Trade in services

          #UI for Services Performance
          servicesperformance_ui(id = 'servicesperformance'),
          #End of UI Services Performance

          #UI for Macroeconomic
          Macroeconomic_ui(id = "Macroeconomic"),
          #End of UI Macroeconomic

          #UI for Digital
          Digital_ui(id = "Digital")
          #End of UI Digital
          
        )
      )
    )
  )
#### End Create User Interface #####


#### Create Server actions #####
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  #Initialize color palette
  mycolor <- color_palette(id = "color")
  
  #Initialize reporter
  reporter_iso_sel <-
    reporter_download_server(id = "reporterdownload")
  
  #Initialize trade flow parameter
  tradeflow <- tradeflow_server(id = "tradeingoods")
  
  #Initialize Services trade flow parameter
  services_tradeflow <- Services_tradeflow_server(id = "tradeinservices")
  
  
 
  #### Demographics ####
   demographics_server(id = "demographics",
                       reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel)
  #### Demographics ####

  #### Trade in goods ####
   tradeingoods_1_server(
    id = "tradeingoods",
    reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel,
    reporter = reporter_iso_sel$reporter,
    mycolor = mycolor,
    tradeflow = tradeflow
  )
  #### Trade in goods ####

  #### Trade performance ####
  trade_performance_server(
    id = "tradeperformance",
    reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel,
    reporter = reporter_iso_sel$reporter,
    mycolor = mycolor
  )
  #### Trade performance ####

  
  #### Logistic performance ####
  LPI_server(
    id = "LPI",
    reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel,
    reporter = reporter_iso_sel$reporter,
    mycolor = mycolor
  )
  #### Logistic performance ####

  #### Bilateral Trade ####
  bilateral_server(
    id = "bilateral",
    reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel,
    reporter = reporter_iso_sel$reporter,
    mycolor = mycolor,
    tradeflow = tradeflow
  )
  #### Bilateral Trade ####

  #### Trade Agreements ####
  trade_agreement_server(
    id = "agreement",
    reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel
  )
  #### Trade Agreements ####

  #### Trade in services ####
  # tradeinservices_server(
  #    id = "tradeinservices",
  #    reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel,
  #    reporter = reporter_iso_sel$reporter,
  #    mycolor = mycolor,
  #    services_tradeflow = services_tradeflow
  #  )
  #### Trade in services ####

  #### Services performance ####
  services_performance_server(
    id = "servicesperformance",
    reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel,
    reporter = reporter_iso_sel$reporter,
    mycolor = mycolor
  )
  #### Services performance ####

  #### Macroeconomic ####
  Macroeconomic_server(
    id = "Macroeconomic",
    reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel,
    reporter = reporter_iso_sel$reporter,
    mycolor = mycolor
  )
  #### Macroeconomic ####

  #### Digital ####
  Digital_server(
    id = "Digital",
    reporter_iso_sel = reporter_iso_sel$reporter_iso_sel,
    reporter = reporter_iso_sel$reporter,
    mycolor = mycolor
  )
  #### Digital ####


})
#### End create Server actions #####

#### Run application #####
shinyApp(ui, server)
#### End Run application #####
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to have run in parallel from the modules? Please share a minimal reproducible example, thanks!

Comment: I want to run the output in parallel from each modules. They are independent from each other. Each module is rendering outputs.